# what will be the execution order of the following bit operations?

Tags: c, bitmap, bitwise-operators

I see the following bit operation statement, but what is the order of the execution:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int age = 2;
    unsigned int agemap = 0x111 ;
    if(age > 0 && age <= 32)
    {

       agemap &= (unsigned int)~((unsigned int)1 << (unsigned int)(age - 1));
    }
}
```

This is used to remove the age(value 2) from the agemap(0x111), but based on what order it is executed?

Comment: Your value of agemap = 0x111 which = binary 000100010001 looks problematic for common bit operations.

Comment: why? can you explain

Answer (score 1):

It's of course "based" on the order of precendence of C's operators, like in any other expression. There are plenty of parentheses of course, so you have to take those into account.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) has a good table. Note that it's complicated since C has quite a few operators.

Basically, the right-hand side evaluates to `~(1 << 1)`, which is `~2`, which is 0xfffffffd assuming a 32-bit `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
agemap &= (unsigned int)~((unsigned int)1 << (unsigned int)(age - 1));
```

If you remove (unnecesary) casts:

```
agemap &= ~(1U << (age - 1));
```

1. `age - 1`
2. `1U << 1`
3. `~2`

Comment: ...and `&`ing `~2` with `0x111` should just give an unchanged `0x111`. Which makes me ask, is this code doing what the OP thinks it is?